# How to replace HTML entity by the string character

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a string with multiple different HTML characters in it.
For example:

```
var price = "CHF 150.&ndash; (brutto)";
```

how can I replace the HTML entities like `&ndash;` with the string character like below?

```
"CHF 150.- (brutto)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function replaceHTMLEntities(str) {
  const htmlEntities = {
    '&amp;': '&',
    '&lt;': '<',
    '&gt;': '>',
    '&quot;': '"',
    '&#039;': "'",
    '&ndash;': '-',
  };

  return str.replace(/&[\w#]+;/g, entity => {
    return htmlEntities[entity] || entity;
  });
}
```

Comment: Your list in [incomplete](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `replace()` like so:

```
price.replace('&ndash', '-');
```

[MDN Web Docs - String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score -2):

You could decode it using the native `DOMParser`.

I created a wrapper class that can be reused:

```js
// Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/1762224
class HTMLDecoder {
  constructor() {
    this.parser = new DOMParser();
  }
  decode(input) {
    const doc = this.parser.parseFromString(input, 'text/html');
    return doc.documentElement.textContent;
  }
}

const decoder = new HTMLDecoder(),
      price   = "CHF 150.&ndash; (brutto)";

console.log(decoder.decode(price));

console.log(decoder.decode('&copy; 2023 &quot;Hello World&quot;'));
```

Comment: This question is an obvious duplicate. Add the answer to that duplicate question if it answers it better than the existing answers.